# Running Gutenberg React in Development Mode

Tags: customization, block-editor

Is there a way to enable WordPress to run the non-minified version of React while developing Gutenberg blocks?

I am receiving an error from React while learning to create Gutenberg blocks.

```
react-dom.min.b75d8b30.js:62 Error: Minified React error #130; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

It would be very helpful to get the full error. I am using the Gutenberg suggested abstraction, `wp.element.createElement` in order to create the elements. So my plugin has no direct access to React.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It took me way too long to find this but all you have to do is set SCRIPT_DEBUG to true. Simply add this line to wp-config.php:

```
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: Pretty crazy it was so simple, it should be the first topic in the Gutenberg Handbook, not buried down here... https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: I totally agree